# Kindly explain the engine log and solutions in my c-plex output?

Tags: windows, output, runtime-error, cplex, opl

Can you explain this?

Engine log

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at documentation

CPLEX > CPLEX Optimizers > User's Manual for CPLEX > Continuous optimization > Solving LPs: simplex optimizers > Diagnosing LP infeasibility

> Interpreting solution quality Documents facilities for evaluating
> solution quality in LP models

Comment: Here the maximum bound infeasibility is in the range of e^6.What does it indicates. Whether  my solution quality is poor?